# How to search and replace content type (system)name in database for product types

Tags: commerce, nodes, database

Using Commerce kickstart, I wanted to replace the existing example content type names with other names.
I downloaded the database, applied a search and replace, and after uploading the database and clearing caches, the website now shows new content types plus the old ones. 
It appears that the website has recreated the old content types..but I have no idea what does that and how to prevent that.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that commerce kickstart uses features in order to create the demo store, and that the content types cannot be deleted. Apparently they are recreated by features when the machine name of the content type is not present any more.

See https://www.drupal.org/node/1796468